# Fastlane and TeamCity

Tags: teamcity, macos-sierra, fastlane

I have installed fastlane on my MacOS.
When I run fastlane command from terminal window all it's work. 
But when the same command is executed from TeamCity build agent (gulp task) **comand not found** is displayed.

```
> [15:34:27][Step 1/1] [15:31:06] exec(fastlane beta) 
> [15:34:27][Step1/1] /bin/sh: fastlane: command not found
```

Fastlane automatically was installed in my user folder **/Users/myusername/.fastlane/bin** and I included this path in global paths (**/etc/paths.d/**) and for my fastlane is accesibile from any location but for TC build agent not...

How to solve this issue? How to install fastlane globally?

Answer (score 4):

Problem solved.

Initially was:

```
exec('fastlane beta');
```

and I changed to:

```
exec('export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.fastlane/bin"; fastlane beta');
```